# Find possible coordinates of a square

Tags: geometry

Given two adjacent coordinates of square as $(X1,Y1)$ and $(X2,Y2)$ How to find the other two  possible coordinates so that a square can be obtained.I know their will be 2 possible squares.But how to find them in an easy way?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let $P_i$ be the point represented as $a_i+ib_i\ (i=1,2,3,4)$ where $a_i,b_i\in\mathbb R$.

Then, we have
$$(a_3+ib_3)-(a_2+ib_2)=\pm i((a_1+ib_1)-(a_2+ib_2))$$
$$\Rightarrow a_3+ib_3=(\mp b_1\pm b_2+a_2)+i(\pm a_1\mp a_2+b_2)$$
$$\Rightarrow a_3=\mp b_1\pm b_2+a_2,\ \ b_3=\pm a_1\mp a_2+b_2.$$

Also, we have
$$(a_4+ib_4)-(a_1+ib_1)=\mp i((a_2+ib_2)-(a_1+ib_1))$$
$$\Rightarrow a_4+ib_4=(\pm b_2\mp b_1+a_1)+i(\mp a_2\pm a_1+b_1)$$
$$\Rightarrow a_4=\pm b_2\mp b_1+a_1,\ \ b_4=\mp a_2\pm a_1+b_1.$$

Hence, the answer is the followings :

$$P_3(-b_1+b_2+a_2,+a_1-a_2+b_2),P_4(+b_2-b_1+a_1,-a_2+a_1+b_1).$$
or
$$P_3(+b_1-b_2+a_2,-a_1+a_2+b_2),P_4(-b_2+b_1+a_1,+a_2-a_1+b_1).$$

**P.S. 1** :  In other words, 
$$P_3(-Y_1+Y_2+X_2,+X_1-X_2+Y_2),P_4(+Y_2-Y_1+X_1,-X_2+X_1+Y_1).$$
or
$$P_3(+Y_1-Y_2+X_2,-X_1+X_2+Y_2),P_4(-Y_2+Y_1+X_1,+X_2-X_1+Y_1).$$

**P.S. 2** : Given the coordinates of two points $(X_1,Y_1),(X_2,Y_2)$ for diagonal of square, the other points $(X,Y)$ can be found as the following :

$$(X+iY)-(X_1+iY_1)=\frac{1}{\sqrt 2}(\cos (\pm 45^\circ)+i\sin(\pm 45^\circ))((X_2+iY_2)-(X_1+iY_1))$$
$$\Rightarrow X+iY=\left(\frac{X_2}{2}+\frac{X_1}{2}\mp\frac{Y_2}{2}\pm\frac{Y1}{2}\right)+i\left(\frac{Y_2}{2}+\frac{Y_1}{2}\pm\frac{X_2}{2}\mp\frac{X_1}{2}\right).$$
Hence, the answer is the following :
$$\left(\frac{X_2+X_1-Y_2+Y_1}{2},\frac{Y_2+Y_1+X_2-X_1}{2}\right)$$and$$\left(\frac{X_2+X_1+Y_2-Y_1}{2},\frac{Y_2+Y_1-X_2+X_1}{2}\right).$$

Comment: How to find it if we are given (X1,Y1) and (X2,Y2)

Comment: Letting $X_1=a_1,Y_1=b_1,X_2=a_2,Y_2=b_2$ gives you the coordinate of the other points. Consider in complex plane.

Comment: so can i say coordinates are : (-Y1+Y2+X2+X1,X1-X2+Y2) of this kind ?

Comment: @user119249: Yes. I added a bit. Take a look.

Comment: @user119249: If $X_1=0,Y_1=0,X_2=2,Y_2=2$, then my calculation shows that it gives correct results : $X_3=4,Y_3=0,X_4=2,Y_4=-2$ or $X_3=0,Y_3=4,X_4=-2,Y_4=2$.

Comment: @user119249: I believe that the results I wrote in my answer are correct. Did you read my comment?

Comment: yeah you are correct for this part.I am asking if the coordinates for diagonal of square is given

Comment: did you get what am asking ?

Comment: @user119249: Yes. Now I'm back. Please wait a minute:)

Comment: @user119249: I added the case for the diagonal coordinates. Take a look.

Answer (score 0):

If $(a,b)$ is one of the other two coordinates,

$$(a-X1)^2+(b-Y1)^2=(X2-X1)^2+(Y2-Y1)^2$$

and $$\frac{b-Y1}{a-X1}\cdot\frac{Y2-Y1}{X2-X1}=-1$$

If $(c,d)$ is the fourth, $$\left(\frac{X1+a}2,\frac{Y1+b}2\right),\left(\frac{X2+c}2,\frac{Y2+d}2\right)$$ are the concurrent center of the diagonals

Comment: Can their be more simplified formula for finding ?

Comment: How to find these (a,b) and (c,d) ?

Comment: @user119249, Hope you've understood how they have derived. Can you see two equations of $(a,b)$ in the first two relations?

Comment: I need to compute them through an algorithm.So thats why require a simple approach